# How to get multiple averages from ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, random, arraylist

Code below generates 100 sorted random doubles from 0 to 100, then it's calculating average (avg) from those 100 numbers. My intention was to calculate 10 averages from those numbers and then sort them, but in many tries I get or my 100 sorted-random numbers or 1 average :(

How to get those 10 sorted averages?

```
public class NewMain {
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortowacz(100, 0, 100)));
    }

    public static Object[] sortowacz(final double length, final double min,
                                     final double max) {
        List<Double> nieposortowanaLista = randList(length, min, max);

        Collections.sort(nieposortowanaLista);
        return nieposortowanaLista.toArray();
    }

    private static List<Double> randList(final double length, final double min,
                                         final double max) {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> avg = new ArrayList<>();
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            list.add(min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            sum += list.get(i);
        }

        avg.add(sum / list.size());

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those `10 averages` averages of? :)

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly if you are asking people to read it?

Comment: Whatever the length, you always need 10 averages?

Comment: @Dzmitry Paulenka They are averages of 100 randomly generated numbers

Comment: @Noor Nawaz No, it could be from 10 to 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your required code which calculate 10 averages out of 100 and sort them at the end

```
public class TestAverages {

public static void main(String... args) {

    List<Double> averages = sortowacz(1000, 0, 100);
    averages.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<Double> sortowacz(final double length, final double min, final double max) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        list.add(min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble());
    }

    List<Double> averages = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        List<Double> subList = list.subList(0, (int) (length/10));
        double avg = subList.parallelStream().mapToDouble(d -> d).average().getAsDouble();
        averages.add(avg);
        list.removeAll(subList);
    }
    return averages;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, but I don't understand one thing: If I set 10 averages (list.subList(0, 10)) from 100 random numbers (sortowacz(100, 0, 100)) it gives me what I expect. But when I want to create for example 10 averages from 1000 numbers (i set it like: list.subList(0, 10) and sortowacz(1000, 0, 100)) it gives me 100 averages with strange looking averages :( Why is it like that?

Comment: I have edited the code, not it will work for 1000 or any other number

Comment: Yep but now dispersion of those averages is wrong. When I sorted them (Collections.sort(averages)) i noticed that the first avg value is about 0 and last about 99. When making an avg from a set of random numbers from 0 to 100 its expected to be somewhere between 46 and 54 :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your multiple averages are but to get one you could use

```
List<Double> list=new ArrayList<>();

double average =    list.stream().mapToDouble(d->d).average().getAsDouble();
```